How do I disable ctrl/alt + mousewheel workspace switching in Ubuntu 22.04?
On my previous system I would regularly use ctrl+mousewheel scroll on browsers to zoom in/out of pages. I've upgraded to a new machine and during the setup process I noticed that this was now bound to switching between workspaces. As this was clearly an operating system shortcut I could understand how it would be overwriting any browser behaviour, however I haven't been able to find a setting to disable this.
This also occurs when I hold alt and scroll.
I tried the gsettings solution suggested here but though this disabled the behaviour when the pointer was hovering over the dock with the ctrl/alt keys unpressed, the problem with ctrl/alt pressed persisted.

was this post what you were looking for?

I don't believe that tool would help me. I'm looking for the ability to disable this behaviour which I expect should be possible by default in my Ubuntu install as this has changed between my two copies of the OS

perhaps this one?

I'm afraid not.

Found the solution to this here. Disabling the shortcut key for /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/mouse-button-modifier and restarting my machine solved the issue.
